# what is the best way to call data from MySQL with speed and security in mind?

Tags: php, mysql

can some one provided some suggestions of constructing MySQL querys that are both fast as well as secure.

Currently I am using typical MySQL calling method

```
$q = ("...");
$r = mysql_query($q);
```

but I was looking into OOP database programming so I am wondering which method would be the best to use and implemend on multiple pages with security and speed in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way without much effort would be to use PHP PDO [PHP Data Object] extension. Here is the manual for it:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Example:

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

You should learn the idea of "prepared statements" - it really improves security compared to mysql_query() way.

Comment: A roger that will look into it.

Comment: +1 always use prepared statements, never string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

For security purposes, always use database parameters instead of putting what the user provides directly in the query.  You can do this by either using the mysqli_ family of functions or the PDO object.

For speed, you should just try to optimize your queries as much as possible as well as try to do as few queries as needed because each hit to the database will slow down your application.

Answer (score 1):

The `mysqlnd` library included in PHP >= 5.3 is faster than the original `mysql` and `mysqli` libraries.

Security is a much bigger ball of wax, but the general principle to keep in mind is not to ever trust or assume that user-generated data is safe. Use the string escape functions on strings; make sure things you expect to be ints or floats are typecasted as such.

Comment: A wise words, I agree with you 120% users inputed data can't be so easily trusted but I run it truth multiple validation and striping process before it gets to DB, this does take a bit longer to do then just letting user input plain data, but its better then getting entire DB compromised.

Comment: Database parameters will remove all sanitization for the user's input.  All that you are left with is input validation - making sure your input is what you expect it to be.

Comment: sadly I cant use MYSQLND my PHP version is 5.2.17 so no luck with that, plus I can seem to find much documentation on MYSQLND on PHP.Net so ye will go with PDO then

Comment: -1 Do not use string escape functions, use parameterised queries. These are available even without mysqlnd, using appropriate libraries (e.g. PDO).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to combine most important features in one think in general, PDO provide data-access abstraction layer, so you write once and use your script with different database server's, however, PDO not mush faster then MySQLi as the benchmark [here](http://jonathanrobson.me/2010/06/mysqli-vs-pdo-benchmarks) show, but its provide many other features, query cache, prepared statement, and support most known databases server.

If you really looking for OOP database abstraction layer then use PDO, easy to use, fast to learn.